# Why haven't I received any answer on my question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, questions

#### What makes a good question on Joomla Stack Exchange?

#### How can I help people answer my question?

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people in the Joomla community come to Joomla Stack Exchange to seek help with something, be it extension related, administration related etc. For us to be able to answer you questions, we require *as much information as possible*, simply because we can't read your mind as it also saves us having to ask you a bunch of question before we can compile our final answer.

Here are a list of thing that you should read before writing your question (from [@Brian Teeman's](https://brian.teeman.net/joomla/850-free-joomla-support) blog)

1. **I am having a problem with?**
2. **Describe the problem (no more than 100 words)**
3. **What version of Joomla are you using (in x.y.z format)?**
4. **Which template are you using?**
5. **Did you try using the default Protostar template?**
6. **When did your problem begin?**
7. **Do you have a backup from before the problem began?**
8. **What resources (exact links) have you read?**
9. **Is this an issue with an extension, if so which one?**
10. **If it is an extension issue, have you checked the developers site?**
11. **Link to site so we can see the issue (or screenshots)**
12. **Is registration required to reproduce this issue?**

Comment: +1 For providing as much information as possible. I'd also suggest people don't rush their question. Don't post in haste.